# Magento Seems Incomplete is it?

Tags: magento

I downloaded and installed magento on xampp by bitnami. Here is a screenshot of what i can see once i open localhost/magento :
[image]

I was watching a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2UELmunMeZo&list=PL3B0BAAF482B16EAB) on youtube about magento but he had a bit different view:
[image]

So what i wanted to know was, is my install incomplete? because it lacks the main content it just has the side bar content and the top bar. (Note: In the video the guy had also said that all that was pre-made and he did not add any of that himself) What is it? and if it comes automatically how do i add it? re-install?

Comment: This question better belongs on [MageOverflow](https://magento.stackexchange.com). It is not a programming question, but is specific to Magento.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that guy did not enter all that himself but he uses the sample data provided by magento itself.

Magento has a sample data archive available that contains sample products and CMS pages to allow you to explore your new Magento installation without having to create everything from scratch.

Note: You cannot install that sample data now. You need to re-install with some more steps.

[Here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/installing-the-sample-data-for-magento) is the magento page about all this.